# how to find the black region in near the edge

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have an image like below. It has black border/regions in the top and right side of the image. I want to be able to find these regions like shown in the 2nd images. Note these regions should be always streight (ie rectangle shaped). I want to be able to do this using 'image processing with code not with photoshop' (such as matlab, c# or opencv).

[image: Input image]

[image: output image]

I am very new to 'image process'. I have tried to find all the pionts that have (0,0,0) rgb values. But because there are so many of these black values in the noise part (and any other places in the images). My result region also contains these unwanted region....

---------- Edit --------------- 
Thanks for all the comments/answers. However, I have lots of these images. Some of them are rotated, which is a bit more difficult to deal with. I have just uploaded one as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: @JulienBernu Just edited my post

Comment: select only the rows/columns where all points are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
color_img = imread('0k4Kh.jpg');
img = rgb2gray(color_img);
[x, y] = size(img);

for i = 1:x
    if length(find(img(i, :))) ~= 0
        lastmarginalrow = i-1;
        break;
    end
end

for ii = y:-1:1
    if length(find(img(:, ii))) ~= 0
        lastmarginalcol = ii-1;
        break;
    end
end

figure;
fig = imshow(color_img);
h = impoly(gca, [0,x; lastmarginalcol,x; lastmarginalcol,lastmarginalrow; 0,lastmarginalrow]);
api = iptgetapi(h);
api.setColor('red');
saveas(fig, 'test.jpg');
close all;
```

Here is the implementation in MATLAB. Find zeros column and zeros row and draw a border using them.

**For Rotated Images (should work for non-rotated also)**

```
color_img = imread('N6vK9.png');
img = rgb2gray(color_img);
[x, y] = size(img);

verts = [];
% traversing through all columns
for i = 1:y
    % find all non-zero pixels in each column
    nonzeros = find(img(:,i));
    % if all pixels are black in a column, below if condition will skip
    if length(nonzeros) ~= 0
        % if there is atleast one non-zero pixel, not that co-oridinate/positions in matrix by appending
        verts = [i, nonzeros(1); verts];
    end
end

figure;
fig = imshow(color_img);
% polygon based on first and last vertix/co-ordinate of found non-zero co-ordinates
% Assumed that it was slanted straight line, used last and first co-ordinate. If it is curvy border, anyways we have all veritices/co-ordinates of first non-zero pixel in all columns.
h = impoly(gca, [verts(1,:); verts(length(verts), :); 1,x; verts(1),x]);
api = iptgetapi(h);
api.setColor('red');
saveas(fig, 'test.jpg');
close all;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. SauravGupta gave a similar answer to find non-zeros column/rows ealier as well. Like my above comments to his answer, I have rotated images. Do you have a solution to deal with them?

Comment: this can be vectorised easily by doing something like `min (logical (sum (img, 2)) .* [1 : size (img, 1)]' )` etc. The problem is we're making a lot of assumptions "where" these black areas are, "how many", etc. I'm sure what works specifically for this image won't work for all images in OP's set.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks for the comments. i do not understand what does 'vectorised' mean. but basically my images can be categorised like the above two sets (rotated, not rorated). The rotated ones can have different angles (PS: I do not know the angles).

Comment: @wildcolor added solution for rotated images as well

Comment: @be_good_do_good thanks for the brilliant answer. Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: @be_good_do_good thanks for the brilliant answer. i have accepted your answer. It works well. the only question I want to ask even though nonzeros(1) suppose to store all the first 'none-zero' values. But if there is a 'vertical black gap' in the image, then the algorithm will not work?

Comment: @wildcolor, thank you. Yes it will work, because i am taking 2 corner co-ordinates for drawing polygon. So if even there is column of full zero pixels, it will just skip that column

Comment: @be_good_do_good thanks for the comments. But if the 2nd corner (topright corner) happen to have a few less black points (ie the rightmost vertical column has less nonezeros than the one next to it), the top line of the polygon would be lower than expected?

Comment: Then it is kind of curvy line, rather than a straight line. For that kind of cases, i added comments as well in the code :)
If it is curvy border, anyways we have all veritices/co-ordinates of first non-zero pixel in all columns.

Comment: Else we can add a logic to find the lowest and highest, use them as x-cordinates, so it does not cut any part of the image

Answer (score 1):

Using Python2.7 + OpenCV3. The idea is to keep only non-zero rows and columns. The code follows.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#Read in the image
arr = np.array(cv2.imread('image.jpg'))
#Convert to grayscale
gray = np.sum(arr, axis=2)
print gray.shape #(496, 1536)
filter_row = np.sum(gray,axis=1)!=0
# Assuming first few values are all False, find index of first True, and set all values True after that 
filter_row[list(filter_row).index(True):,] = True
# Keep only non-zero rows
horiz = gray[filter_row,:]

filter_column = np.sum(gray,axis=0)!=0
# Assuming first few values are all False, find index of first False, and set all values True before that 
filter_column[:list(filter_column).index(False),] = True
# Keep only non-zero columns
vert = horiz[:,filter_column]
print vert.shape #(472, 1528)
bordered = cv2.rectangle(cv2.imread('image.jpg'), (0, gray.shape[0]-vert.shape[0]), (vert.shape[1],gray.shape[0] ), (255,0,0), 2)
cv2.imwrite(bordered,'result.jpg')
```

Comment: strictly speaking, this is not the correct answer, as it will also remove rows / columns "within" the image if they happen to have no specks.

Comment: I agree. But I checked the `np.sum(gray,axis=1)!=0` array and all the `False` values are located at the top of the array. And similarly for `np.sum(gray,axis=1)!=0` Lemme modify the code to make sure that only continuous rows/rols from top/right are omitted.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Fixed.

Comment: @SauravGupta thanks for the answer. As soon as I saw your 1st sentance it blows my mind.

Comment: ps: what @TasosPapastylianou said can also be true. This is not the only image that I have. I have many of these images.

Comment: There is a more serious problem. My other images can be rotated, so that the empty (black) areas are no longer horizontal or vertical. Therefore, only finding non-zero rows and columns can no longer be accurate.

Comment: Hmm, can you accept this answer to the original question? As far as the rotation is concerned, if you know the angle, then you can make the image horizontal and this code will work. Please post an example of an rotated image and I'll take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118319/discussion-between-saurav-gupta-and-wildcolor).

Comment: @SauravGupta thanks for the reply. I have added in one rotated image as an example. I really hope that people can have chances to look at the problem. If no one can asnwer it, I will accept your answer. In any case, I just want to let you know that I really really apreciate your help.

Comment: @wildcolor you keep altering your question, which makes things difficult. I can tell you how to remove "connected black regions from corners" (specifically, look at the `bwselect` function in matlab), but you have to ask yourself "how would I make use of that information?". It's one thing to 'crop' an image into a smaller but still valid matrix, and it's another to "obtain a logical mask of pixels that should not be included in the calculation". The type of processing the latter entails is very different. As per the [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/), "what exactly are you trying to do?"

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks for your comment. I am actually writing my own c# code to deal with the images. All I want to do is to find the black regions on the top (and right side), so when I deal with images, I can exclude these areas. Forgive me if my question to you is not veyr clear because I am very new to image processing. You mentioned 2 things that are different. To me it looks the same :( :(